# loading image asset folder in eclipse works fine but not on intelij

Tags: image, intellij-idea, import

The image resources folder 'images' are imported and runs successfully on eclipse. But I have problem running this on IntelliJ.

Can someone enlighten me why it doesn't work on eclipse?

[image]

[image]
Here I tried marking 'images' folder as Sources or resources but none of them works. It is currently not selected because if I select this then it overrides the .classpath file which is currently the same as the one in eclipse.

The image is imported using the following line:

```
imageMap = ImageIO.read(new File("images/map.png"));
```

Which works fine in eclipse.

So why does it not work in IntelliJ?

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print `new File("").getAbsolutePath()` to see what your working directory is. You will then probably see that your relative path is wrong. You can change your Working directory in Run configuration.

Comment: AHHHhhhhh AHHHHHH. Genius sir. 
Indeed my working directory wasn't set up properly. Works beautifully.